# Plupload integration with drupal webform

Tags: drupal-7, plupload, drupal-webform

I have a site in drupal7 and use webform module.
I want to upload multiple file in one go instead of select single image everytime.

These are the modules that doesn't work for me:

1. Webform Multiple File Upload
2. Webform Multiple File

Is there a way to allow file uploads in one go for drupal Webform or any custom method ?

Comment: Given that Webform Multiple File Upload etc. appear to be exactly what you're looking for, could you elaborate on why they "don't work for you"?

Comment: These modules does not allow me to upload more than 1 file in one go.
i.e upload single image one at a time but i want to upload more than 1 image simultanously